# Get client credentials from Simple Oauth module

Tags: javascript, authentication-authorization, http-request

I am creating user authentification with Drupal 9 + NuxtJS.
Using Simple Oauth module and create post requests to

```
oauth/token
```

with data

```
const data = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  client_id: '',
  client_secret: '!',
  username: username,
  password: password,
}
```

So, how can I get this client_id, client_secret to past it in JS file ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these following modules will help you, I was once stuck with the same issue for the authentication. My Drupal application was decoupled (Frontend - Vue and Backend - Drupal 9)

I installed the following contributed modules:
[JWT](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt), and [Get JWT on Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/getjwtonlogin).

And just call the login (https://your-drupal-site/**user/login?_format=json**) endpoint with provided credentials, it will send you back the user's details:

```
{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "1",
        "name": "admin"
    },
    "csrf_token": "UlGb7fak5ZS-r1BRistBh4IWLm_Z7F1xMpY3KYTGqcU",
    "logout_token": "7AvbnHgr9iDxIDVertHTI3PMX2-Shd6sjuN8hNHrHv8F",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLDJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NDg2NzA3NDUsImV4cCI6MTU0ODY3NDM0NSwiZHJ1cGAsIjp7InVpZCI6IjYifX0.cnG6atSLYrRh6D05LZg9RwrJJdYoJfTBXTUZboPhJH3lYf640FmQTkJwwy9E8kg7ot59qyb5qtgIewM3R1KCDw"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try